# .Net (C#) SSRS (rdl) file not getting imported from C:\ to ReportServer

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

The code that you see was taken from MSDN. Upon testing it says invalid path for SOURCE. I agree. They want the source to be a URL in another Reporting Server. However what I need is to be able to copy a RDL file from my C:\ to the Reporting Server. How can I ?

```
    static void move_report(string currentPath, string targetPath )
    {

        ReportingService2010 service = new ReportingService2010();
        ReportingService2010 rs = new ReportingService2010();

        rs.Url = "http://MHPDW2/ReportServer/" + "ReportService2010.asmx";
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;


        try
        {
            rs.MoveItem(currentPath, targetPath);
        }

        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.OuterXml);
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string currentPath = "H:\\ITTFS2012\\SSRS\\DW15Reports\\Claims\\6.1 universe.rdl";
        string targetPath = "http://MHPDW2/ReportServer/MidwestHealthPlan/Claims/HPMS/MCR Plan Code/H5685 2014 HPMS/";

        move_report(currentPath,targetPath);
```

Comment: Have a look to: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43133/Deploying-Reports-in-Reporting-Services-Programmat

Comment: What is the question? Did you try the address of your report server? Did you use the correct URL for your SQL Server version? That web service is suitable for SQL Server 2008 R2.  What is the *actual* error?

Comment: Did you try publishing from inside Visual Studio? What address did you use there? Use the same one here

Comment: rs.MoveItem will not accept a hard coded path to the rdl file. It has to be a URL. So we cannot use this method. Instead I found another method which does the job, rs.CreateCatalogItem method does it! Thanks for the help anyway !

Answer (score 0):

What does "H:\" drive resolve to and do you have access to the source location?

Comment: rs.MoveItem will not accept a hard coded path to the rdl file. It has to be a URL. So we cannot use this method. Instead I found another method which does the job, rs.CreateCatalogItem method does it! Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Team:
I found the answer. Everything is here ( including code ) 
I had to use the rs.CreateCatalogItem method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createcatalogitem.aspx